# Any difference between 'it is impossible' and 'it is not possible'?

Tags: differences, sentence

I am working as software engineer.

I have to use sentences like 'it is impossible' or it is not possible' in many emails.

I want to know that both are same or some has more impossible look than other?

Comment: Is there an equivalent of the single word “impossible” in your mother tongue? If so, is there a difference between “impossible” and “not possible” in your language? The short answer is they mean the same thing.

Comment: @DanBron No, in our language we have not  a single word  for impossible, in our language we have to always use equal two words for not possible

Answer (score 1):

Practically speaking, I would say there is no difference. However, I believe there is a very subtle difference.

Consider:

> "Can I talk to the manager?"
>
> "No, I'm afraid that's not possible." (She's busy at the moment.)
> "No, I'm afraid that's impossible." (She's dead.)

Or, better:

> Because the stores are all closed, it's not currently possible to go shopping.
> Because the stores are all closed, it's currently impossible to go shopping.

I would argue that the phrase *currently impossible*, while technically correct, is not one that is as commonly used.

To me, *impossible*, at least in this sense, implies more of a permanence than does *not possible*. With *not possible*, the situation may be permanent; but with *impossible*, it's less likely to be temporary.

So (again, to me), *not possible* means an arbitrary set of circumstances whereby something just happens to not be the case at the moment. Meanwhile,  *impossible* means a categorical situation that can never be met (1+1=3).

However, that very subtle and debatable difference aside (and I've certainly heard people say "that's impossible" in response to a temporary situation when being asked for someone or something), they are interchangeable.

Comment: I agree with the subtle connotation of permanence or difficulty in using "impossible". The franchise isn't called *Mission: Not Possible* for a reason!